# Which schema allow trailing comma for VS appsettings.json?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I hope use VS `appsettings.json` like VSCode `settings.json`, allow trailing commma and comment, which schema should choice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

VS Code uses a superset syntax of JSON, called JSONC, or “JSON with Comments”, for its various settings files. These files can include user settings as well as some configuration files for extensions.

Along with `// single-line comments`, JSONC sometimes supports trailing commas, but it varies by file (I think depending on the file’s schema). See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102061) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not allow trailing commas. This is unrelated to JSON Schema.

Javascript sometimes allows trailing commas. This might be your confusion.

Comment: Curious on the reason for downvoting?